How do I assign a monetary value to each array within Ruby?
I'm creating a Ruby program that ask how many computers you want and its has arrays for computers, monitors, and a free item. I want to add a cost to each of the arrays. If I could add a value to each item within the array that would be great but may be too complicated for me to understand as a beginner.
what I have thus far:
def computer_order()
    puts "how many computers with monitors would you like today?"
    number = gets.chomp
    number = number.to_i
    number
end

def monitor_and_computer()
    computer_type = ["Dell Inspiron", "HP Pro", "Acer Vero", "Lenovo Ideacentre", "Dell Optiplex", "HP Envy"]
    monitor_type = ["Dell 27' Curved", "Viewsonic 22' Flat", "LG 24' Flat", "Samsung 27' Curved", "Spectre 27' Flat", "MSI 31.5' Curved"]
    free_item = ["250G Thumb drive", " Shop T-Shirt", "25$ Steam Gift Card"]
    cost = 600

    number_of_computers = computer_order()
    number_of_computers = number_of_computers.to_i
    total = (number_of_computers * cost)
    total = total.to_s

    number_of_computers.times do 
        puts "One computer is  " +  computer_type.sample + ", " + monitor_type.sample + ", " + free_item.sample
    end 
       puts "Your total is: $" + total
end
    
    monitor_and_computer()


After a user enters a number, e.g. 3, your code will randomly make 3 combinations of a computer, a monitor and a free item. Is that what you want to do? Do you know what are the cost of each item?

@kevinluo201 Yes, I want to output a combination of a computer, monitor and a free item. I don't know the actual cost of the items, no. The true real world cost is not important though. It could be made up figures.

You could use a Hash e.g. computer_type = {"Dell Inspiron" => 300.0, "HP Pro" => 600.0}; or you could create a formal object e.g class Computer; attr_reader :name, :cost; def initialize(name: ,cost:); @name = name; @cost = cost;end;end; and then construct objects computer_type =[Computer.new(name: "Dell Inspiron", cost: 300.0), Computer.new(name: "HP Pro", cost: 600.0).

@engineersmnky Thank you, I've never used Hashes before. If I were to use the Hash method how would I combine my values from the computer_type and monitor_type lines? What would my cost and total variables turn into?

@DRey that would really be up to you here are the docs for Hash maybe pay particular attention to methods like each, keys, and values

I think you can try this first. Use Hash to group the price and the name information of products together first and then extract the data you want.
def computer_order
  puts "how many computers with monitors would you like today?"
  number = gets.chomp
  number = number.to_i
  number
end

def monitor_and_computer
  computer_types = [
    {
      name: "Dell Inspiron", 
      price: 100
    },
    {
      name: "HP Pro", 
      price: 200
    },
    {
      name: "Acer Vero", 
      price: 300
    },
    {
      name: "Lenovo Ideacentre", 
      price: 400
    },
    {
      name: "Dell Optiplex", 
      price: 500
    },
    {
      name: "HP Envy",
      price: 600
    }
  ]
  monitor_types = [
    {
      name: "Dell 27' Curved", 
      price: 200
    },
    {
      name: "Viewsonic 22' Flat", 
      price: 300
    },
    {
      name: "LG 24' Flat", 
      price: 400
    },
    {
      name: "Samsung 27' Curved", 
      price: 500
    },
    {
      name: "Spectre 27' Flat", 
      price: 600
    },
    {
      name: "MSI 31.5' Curved",
      price: 700
    }
  ]
  free_items = ["250G Thumb drive", "Declan's Shop T-Shirt", "25$ Steam Gift Card"]

  total = 0
  number_of_computers = computer_order
  number_of_computers.times do
    computer = computer_types.sample
    monitor = monitor_types.sample
    free_item = free_items.sample

    total += computer[:price] + monitor[:price]
    puts "One computer is #{computer[:name]}, #{monitor[:name]}, #{free_item}"
  end
  puts "Your total is: $#{total}"
end
    
monitor_and_computer

After implementing this, you can let user input the model name they want instead of the number of computers. You can use find to find the element they want in the products' arrays, for example,
computer_types.find { |c| c[:name] == 'HP Pro' }
# => {:name=>"HP Pro", :price=>200}


Alternatively you could define a custom class, e.g. Product = Data.define(:name, :price) so you can have actual method calls like computer.name instead of dealing with hash keys.

@kevinluo201 Thank you, I think I understand a bit better now. And everyone else thank you for your help, it is much appreciated!

You're welcome. After you get more familiar with Ruby and OOP (object oriented programming), you will understand @Stefan 's suggestion. You can read this book, https://www.poodr.com/ . btw, you can set this answer as best answer, it can give me a bit more score, lol
